# Is there software that allows me to search for code within php files?

Tags: php, html, search

I have hundreds of php files inside one of my website directories and I was wondering if there is a way to just search for a string...or line of code inside all the php files instead of having to open dreamweaver and search for the line 1 file at a time?

Comment: Do you use an IDE of any type? Anyof thme do, and I would look at some advanced search programs, or grep type of progams.

Comment: thanks, works perfectly... i cant believe i did not know about this, it would have saved me days of programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on OSX/Linux you can do a shell command:

> grep -rH "string to search for" directory/of/files/

If you are on windows, you could start using an IDE like Eclipse / Aptana which lets you search within all files inside the project.

Comment: Or, on Windows, use `find` or `findstr`.

Comment: Ya its nice to have a *nix shell to do these things instead of requiring complete applications in Windows to support the feature.

Answer (score 1):

Not only php file, but all text-based files could be searched for strings with **Useful File Utilities**. Furthermore, you can even replace the string with another string in all files.

It's pretty old software but it's **free** at all, you can find it here : http://www.replsoft.com/

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to take a look at [Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/). Ctags will map your source code files for declarations - so it won't help you find a particular line of code, but it will help you easily find your functions' and classes' definitions.